# How to clear text area with a button in html using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, button, textarea

I have button in html

```
<input type="button" value="Clear"> 
<textarea id='output' rows=20 cols=90></textarea>
```

If I have an external javascript (.js) function, what should I write?

Comment: also can do as general $('textarea').val('').

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Change in your html with adding the function on the button click

```
 <input type="button" value="Clear" onclick="javascript:eraseText();"> 
    <textarea id='output' rows=20 cols=90></textarea>
```

Try this in your js file:

```
function eraseText() {
    document.getElementById("output").value = "";
}
```

Comment: By far most elegant and simple.

Answer (score 8):

You need to attach a `click` event handler and clear the contents of the textarea from that handler.

HTML

```
<input type="button" value="Clear" id="clear"> 
<textarea id='output' rows=20 cols=90></textarea>
```

JS

```
var input = document.querySelector('#clear');
var textarea = document.querySelector('#output');

input.addEventListener('click', function () {
    textarea.value = '';
}, false);
```

and here's the [working demo](http://cssdeck.com/labs/palvpxbe).

Comment: prior to IE 9 `addEventListener` does not exist, this should be noted.

Comment: indeed, hence use `attachEvent('click', function () {});` for IE8 and below. Also instead of `querySelector` use `getElementById` for IE7 and below. Cheers!

Answer (score 6):

**Using the jQuery library, you can do:**

```
<input type="button" value="Clear" onclick="javascript: functionName();" >
```

You just need to set the onclick event, call your desired function on this onclick event.

```
function functionName()
{
    $("#output").val("");
}
```

Above function will set the value of text area to empty string.

Comment: if you use a library that is not mention by the question you should tell which one you use. for an `onclick` the `javascript:` prefix is not required because it is already clear that it is javascript. anyway if you recommend a library like jquery, you probably also should show how to do add event listeners with that library instead of mixing them into the html code.

Answer (score 1):

Your Html

```
<input type="button" value="Clear" onclick="clearContent()"> 
<textarea id='output' rows=20 cols=90></textarea>
```

Your Javascript

```
function clearContent()
{
    document.getElementById("output").value='';
}
```

Answer (score -4):

You can simply use the **ID** attribute to the form and attach the `<textarea>` tag to the form like this:

```
<form name="commentform" action="#" method="post" target="_blank" id="1321">
    <textarea name="forcom" cols="40" rows="5" form="1321" maxlength="188">
        Enter your comment here...
    </textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="OK">
    <input type="reset" value="Clear">
</form>
```