# How to clear a message after submited without refreshing the page

Tags: javascript

I have a input form, to submit a message. After I submitted my message the text is still in the text area. How do I clear the test area once it is submitted without reloading the page? Do I need javascript to do that?

```
<form method="post" action="mess_add.php" target="list_mess">
<textarea cols="28" rows="3" name="text" maxlength="20000" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) document.getElementById('post').click(); myToken()">
</textarea>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" id="post"/></form>
```

Comment: Yes, you do need Javascript to do that. What Javascript code have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

See: [How to clear text area with a button in html using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15968911/how-to-clear-text-area-with-a-button-in-html-using-javascript)

In this case, you want something like this:

```
document.querySelector('textarea[name=text]').value = '';
```

---

UPDATE:

It might also be worth checking out JavaScript's [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener):

```
<script>
  var form = document.querySelector('form'); // Use an ID if there are multiple forms.
  var textarea = document.querySelector('textarea[name=text]');
  var button = document.querySelector('#post');

  // When the form is submitted, clear the textarea.
  form.addEventListener('submit', function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
      textarea.value = '';
    }, 100);
    return true; // Confirms that it's OK to continue submitting the form.
  });

  // When the return key is typed, submit the form.
  textarea.addEventListener('keypress', function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
      button.click();
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Please i tried but didn't work and i also did it like this onkeydown="document.querySelector('textarea[name=text]').value = '';" and it on make my textarea 1lenght

Comment: Try putting your JavaScript in `<script>...</script>` tags, not inline, it will be *much* easier for answers to see what you're doing (and less of a catastrophe when you need >1 line of code). Updating my answer in a moment.

Comment: It worked but it lost after submitted, like it clear it and return my that input is empty from PHP

Comment: Fixed, it needed a timeout to trigger the form to clear *after* the form is submitted.

Comment: I tried to add this on it how can i do that?`// Please here is giving me problem to add allow me press shift + enter key to move to new line instead of submitting please i don't know what i did here change all to work with above code in up
   else if (e.keyCode === 13 && e.shiftKey) {
           var content = this.value;
           var caret = getCaret(this);
           textarea.value = content.substring(0,caret)+"\n"+content.substring(carent,content.length-1);
});`

Comment: Could you update your question and include a JSFiddle? This is getting away from the original question.